# Need Suggesstion to create WCF DataContarct

Tags: wcf

My SQL store procedure returns 3 tables. And 1 table is mail table other 2 are child tables of first table. For this how i create DataContract in WCF using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you keep the API as clean as possible. Use AutoMapper to copy properties from your database to the WCF Data Classes.

```
[DataContract]
public class Mail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Subject {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public ChildTableData1 ChildData1 {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public ChildTableData2 ChildData2 {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class ChildTableData1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Text {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class ChildTableData2
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```